# Error:(3, 0) Could not get unknown property 'classes' for root project..... Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have 2 gradle project like library. I pull it from git and I can not build it. I have error:

```
Error:(3, 0) Could not get unknown property 'classes' for root project 'my project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

And show this line:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```

full build.gradle

```
group 'my group'

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.typesafe:config:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.0'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Show us the complete build file.

Comment: @ JB Nizet  I add full config

Comment: It seems you just forgot to apply the java plugin, at the top of the file: `apply plugin: 'java'`. Or maybe this is a sub-project build, and the java plugin is applied by the root project. In this case, you should go into the root project and execute something like `./gradlew :myproject:build`. You should also not have a space inside the group.

Comment: Yes, thanks! It's strange that the repository is committed without this line. Maybe the one who did forgot

Comment: yes it sub-project. ok  thanks!

Comment: If JBNizets comment helped you to solve your problem, please add and accept an answer describing how exactly you solved it to help future readers.